# (Advanced Custom Fields Plugin) How can I set true/false field value to always be false instead of NULL

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I’ve been trying to sort first page products with true/false field. As it is true the product is supposed to appear on first page.
I used this meta_query to show all products

```
‘meta_query’ => array(
‘relation’ => ‘OR’,
array(
‘key’ => ‘show_on_first_page’,
‘compare’ => ‘EXISTS’,
),
array(
‘key’ => ‘show_on_first_page’,
‘compare’ => ‘NOT EXISTS’,
)
),
```

This mixes up all the products but if acf true/false field has been checked once it shows the products in the right order. Is there a way to set acf true/false field to be false globally on default if it is set to NULL?

Comment: If it is either exists or not exists, then it's all... Right?

Comment: Yes correct. @HowardE

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_60ca0457d6821', 'my_acf_load_field');

function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
        $field['default_value'] = 0;
        return $field;
    }
```

Where `key=field_60ca0457d6821` update to the key of the true/false field in your case.

This will need adding to functions.php.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how this answers the question?

Comment: It seems like a good idea and if definitely takes me a step closer but the default value still remained true after using this function.

Comment: I have just tested the above method and the acf true/false field does pre-populate true or false based on 1 or 0 default values.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).